# optgroup on mobile/chrome appears with radio button

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a very simple html select field that uses several optgroups to structure the options and it works as intended. However, on android phones and chrome, the optgroup labels have some sort of radio button in front of them (just like the individual options) - "Interesse und Information" would be the optgroup.

[image: optgroup problem]

Now as they are not clickable this is a little confusing. I haven't been able to find the reason or a solution (other than not using optgroups) - am I missing something or do I have to live with it?

The select-field does not use any css.

edit: here's the code:

```
<select id="auswahl">
  <option value="" disabled>Frage auswählen</option>
  <optgroup label="Sonstiges">
    <option value="q3_3">Zustimmung: Helfe gerne</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Interesse und Information">
    <option value="q5">Interesse an Politik</option>
    <option value="q6">Informationsquellen zu Politik</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: ...and your code?